# function to get data into X values ( square_feet) Y values (Price)

Tags: python

1.I stored one data set into a .csv file, named input_data.csv

2.And I write a function to get the data into X values ( square_feet) Y values (Price)

as followed:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Function to get data

def get_data(file_input_data):
    data = pd.read_csv(file_input_data)
    X_parameter = []
    Y_parameter = []
    for single_square_feet ,single_price_value in zip(data['Square_Feet'],data['Price']):
        X_parameter.append([float(single_square_feet)])
        Y_parameter.append(float(single_price_value))
    return(X_parameter,Y_parameter)
```

But...
When I try to print out X_parameter
There is an error :NameError: name 'X_parameter' is not defined

Comment: Please don't post images of your code. Copy paste your code in to the question and use the formatting tools to have it displayed appropriately.

Comment: X_parameter is defined inside the function. It's not know outside. Assign the return value of the function to say X, Y and print them and BTW, as idjaw said paste the code directly.

Comment: I was thinking if, at the forth line, def get_data(file_input_data) is wrong...

Comment: Probably silly question: is that all your code? Have you run your function before printing `X_parameter`?